# How to determine server side performance constraints ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance

- I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC 5 web app
- The dashboard has several charts that retrieve data asynchronously via ajax
- They pull results from memory cache typically, unless a user manually clicks a refresh button, which then pulls the data from the SQL Server database
- When you load the dashboard page, there is one chart that takes about 30sec and then is erroring out. It seems as though this is holding up all the other chart ajax responses as well as they all are reporting about 30sec times
- However, if you then click the refresh button on one of those same charts, it performs that task in 27ms! And that is doing a re-load from the DB, not from cache.

What is happening here? At first I thought it was a client side issue where maybe the 30sec request was getting fired first and the others were queued behind it, but the devtools shows they all get fired simultaneously. So it has to be server side. Why would pulling form memory cache take so long? Am I hitting max request limits from IIS or something (I doubt it because this is on my local dev machine so I can't imagine this loading of a single page would max that out)? What else would cause this or can you point me in a direction to look? I'll admit I've done almost no performance triage in the past so I'm not aware of where to even begin.

Here are some devtools images.

See all these requests loading during a full page load. Note most are taking about 30sec.
[image]

Here, if we compare the timing of the same request...the first is done during the full page load as seen in the above image and took 31.31ms and retrieved the data from cache (I can confirm this from mini-profiler as I have sql logging on, and this request had no sql aspect). Then I clicked the refresh button on this chart after the page fully loaded, and that time, the request only took 27ms and had to get the data from SQL Server instead of cache).
[image]

By contrast (to see a true client side issue), I do see one of the request was stalled. I see [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/issues) that chrome limits you to 6 simultaneous requests...I did not know that :) So I could see why this one would get held up by the longer 30sec one if fired after that one.

[image]

Comment: Hey Chad,
If I was in your shoe, I would start by identifying the source of the dely. 
Is it from the Code,Server,NetworkBrowser?
#Code: Calculate time before and after (System ticks) and write it to the log.
If its heavy data you may want to move the logic to stored procedure its way faster.
#Server: same code will it run faster on your local? not sure where is your app hosted. your local might be faster!
#Network may be server too far, limit on bandwidth
#Browser, Too much processing on client side, Browser limitation (from what you said looks unlikely but I would keep that in mind)

Comment: Thanks @Mamdouh, but I think I've identified that is server side. Its on my local machine, so it's not Network. It's not client side as the dev tools shows all the requests get submitted right away and simultaneously (except that last one that is stalled). Its not SQL because the data is coming from server cache. The server side Mini-Profiler is also showing these as 30sec responses, so the requests are getting to the server (i.e. it's not IIS socket waiting, etc). What other server side aspect could be the source or the delay?

Comment: so these delays are even after Controller does all of its logic? and delay is between Server and Client.

Below link talks about "ASP.NET limitation of the number of worker threads" not sure if you came across it. hope it helps
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/aspnet/performance-call-web-service
and this looks similar
https://www.leansentry.com/Guide/IIS-AspNet-Hangs